Vim: change definition of 'word' only for motion, but not for syntax highlighting
I like to navigate my text files word-by-word using w and b but I find this skips over too many characters in, for example, code. I think I really only want to skip over [a-zA-Z0-9]*. I did RTFM :help word and it points to the iskeyword functionality. However, if I change that, suddenly my syntax highlighting breaks since it seems to be on a word-basis (f.ex. is_same_v is no longer syntax highlighted because it's no longer a single "unit" I presume).
Is there a way to change the definition of a word only for cursor motion, but not for syntax highlighting?
